# SVG image as background image in windows phone 8 and phonegap

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, svg

I am using the SVG image as background in a phonegap project for windows phone8 but its not showing. following is the code

```
.loyaltystar { 
    position:absolute; margin-top:3px;
    background:url(../img/available-icon.svg) no-repeat;
    width:21px; 
    height:21px; 
}

<li><a href="a.html" class="loyaltystar"></a></li>
```

is phonegap 2.4 supports the SVG for windows phone 8.

Comment: Have you tried it in a standalone web page on the phone?

Comment: yes its not working ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the solution removed the xml start tag from the image and its working now ...

Comment: This fixed it for me, but can someone explain why this happens? I don't thing it's an IE problem, because in the browser on windows phone 8 this problem doesn't occur.

Comment: Which xml tag? I'm having the same problem (I know 2 years later...)

Comment: @SunnyOnesotrue starting xml tag like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Answer (score 1):

Include the 'background-size' style, like this:

```
.loyaltystar {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  height: 21px;
  width: 21px;
  background: url(../img/available-icon.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: 21px 21px;
}
```

Otherwise, it could be a path issue with *../img/available-icon.svg*.  Make sure the URL for your image is relative to the URL of your CSS stylesheet (not your HTML page).

Comment: No problem is not with the path. I tried this but not working.